# Replace dynamic string value using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dynamic, replace

Here's the question: How can I replace a value in a string that can vary?
I'm guessing you need to use a regex..

Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
  var height = 500;

  var urlstr = "...?height=300&width=200";

  var newurl = urlstr.replace("height=%&","height="+height+"&");

  alert(newurl);
```

Notice that I'm currently trying to account for the dynamic value using a "%" sign, however this doesn't work.. I'm not great at using regex and would be grateful if any of you could give me a hint, or alternately tell me if I'm approaching this wrongly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you'll need regex. Fortunately it isn't very complicated:

```
var height = 500;
var urlstr = "...?height=300&width=200";
var newurl = urlstr.replace(/(height=)([0-9]+)/, '$1' + height);

alert(newurl);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, if you don't mind me asking, what does this bit do '$1' ?  I'm a little bit confused by that part.. PS blender rules :)

Comment: `$1` refers to the first matched group, which is `height=`. I was lazy and didn't want to write out `height=` so I matched it with `$1` instead. `$2` holds the contents of the old height, just in case you'll ever need it.

Comment: And yes, Blender rules ;) It's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

"%" will be urlencoded "%25".
for your ref,
javascript encodeURIComponent